# How does the Intent with Parcelable pass between two App?

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I have got Service in android app2. I want to start Service from app1 and pass Album object in Intent to Service in app2.

In app1

```
var alb: Album = Album()
alb.name="album name"
alb.numOfSongs=1
alb.thumbnail=2

var serviceIntent: Intent = Intent();
var componentName: ComponentName = ComponentName("com.eusecom.demoad","com.eusecom.demoad.view.EkasaService")
serviceIntent.setComponent(componentName)
serviceIntent.putExtra("albumpar", alb)
context.startService(serviceIntent)
```

In app2 in Service class

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Album alb = intent.getParcelableExtra("albumpar");

}
```

I can to pass String in Intent. If i put to Intent the Parcelable i get error.

> 02-27 14:12:18.438 22198-22198/com.eusecom.demoad E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.eusecom.samshopersung.models.Album
>                                                               java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eusecom.samshopersung.models.Album
>                                                                   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                                   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
>                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2517)
>                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2471)
>                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2374)
>                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2727)
>                                                                   at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:269)
>                                                                   at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:992)
>                                                                   at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:6743)
>                                                                   at com.eusecom.demoad.view.EkasaService.onStartCommand(EkasaService.java:29)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3685)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap23(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1740)
>                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
>                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
>                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
>                                                                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.eusecom.samshopersung.models.Album" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.eusecom.demoad-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.eusecom.demoad-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
>                                                                   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
>                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>                                                                   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
>                                                                   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400) 
>                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2517) 
>                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2471) 
>                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2374) 
>                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2727) 
>                                                                   at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:269) 
>                                                                   at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:992) 
>                                                                   at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:6743) 
>                                                                   at com.eusecom.demoad.view.EkasaService.onStartCommand(EkasaService.java:29) 
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3685) 
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap23(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1740) 
>                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692) 
>                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
>                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358) 
>   02-27 14:12:18.439 22198-22198/com.eusecom.demoad D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   02-27 14:12:18.440 22198-22198/com.eusecom.demoad E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                       Process: com.eusecom.demoad, PID: 22198
>                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.eusecom.demoad.view.EkasaService@fe9af21 with Intent { cmp=com.eusecom.demoad/.view.EkasaService launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } (has extras) }: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.eusecom.samshopersung.models.Album
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3702)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap23(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1740)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
>                                                                        Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.eusecom.samshopersung.models.Album
>                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2545)
>                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2471)
>                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2374)
>                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2727)
>                                                                           at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:269)
>                                                                           at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:992)
>                                                                           at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:6743)
>                                                                           at com.eusecom.demoad.view.EkasaService.onStartCommand(EkasaService.java:29)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3685)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap23(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1740) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692) 
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

Comment: is Album implementing Parcelable?

Comment: @Antonis Radz Of course. I have implemented parcelable in both app in classes Album

Comment: No, you can't directly parcel and share objects from one app to other in my opinion. You'll need to create **Content Provider** in one app and access it using **Content Resolver** in another. *(Main issue during unmarshalling in second app is that particular class name `com.eusecom.samshopersung.models.Album` doesn't exists in second app, obviously.. package name differs)*

Comment: Does the `Album` class have exactly the same fully qualified class name in both apps?

Comment: @ David Wasser Class Name is the same Album but of course package is differ.

Comment: If package names differ, these are different classes. BTW, they should remain the same even after obfuscation, if you ever use it.

Comment: Different package names is why the second app cannot unmarshall the extra from the `Intent`. See my answer for a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off serializing the object to a String, passing the String in the `Intent` and then deserialize the String to an object in the target application.

Comment: What is max size of String in Intent ?

Comment: About 1MB, maybe a bit less. If your object is very large you would be better off storing it in a database or a file instead of putting it in an `Intent`